# android button continuously generate strings

Tags: java, android, button

When I press a button it prints one of the strings at random, but I can only do it once then I have to restart the app and press again to print a new one. What do I have to do to be able to continuously press the button and continuously print the strings at random?

```
public String converse = randomStarter();

public String randomStarter() {
    Random generator = new Random();
    int rand = generator.nextInt(6);
    String starter = new String("");

    switch (rand) {
        case 0: starter = "What was your favorite subject in \n school as a kid? \n Worst?"; 
            break;

        case 1: starter = "My favorite room in the house is...";
            break;

        case 2: starter = "If you had 1 million dollars, what would you do with it?";
            break;

        case 3: starter = "Did you ever have a nickname? \n If so, what was it?";
            break;

        case 4: starter = "If I had magical powers I would...";
            break;

        case 5: starter = "If you were invisible for a day, \nwhat would you do?";
            break;

        case 6: starter = "5 people I would NOT like to meet...";
            break;
    }

    return starter;
}
```

xml code for text field:

```
   <TextView android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:textColor="#2f4b66"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/dummy_content" />
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you set the text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code's hinting that you use `converse` as your 'random' string. If you want to generate new random stings, you'll have to call `randomStarter()` every time.

If this is not the case, please show the code where you're using the random string.

Comment: do you mean before the break in the case statements? i tried that, but it just crashes the app...

Comment: I mean every time that you're trying to use the random string. Once you've set `converse`, it'll remain the same as the function `randomStarter()` is only called a single time.

Comment: oh, I see now! i'll give it a try.